# Fatal Error Visual Studio Code / git

Tags: git, macos, vscode

Estoy usando git en MacOS y tengo un problema.

en vez de agregar la carpeta deseada, tipie "git add ." en la terminal, a lo cual, creo la carpeta .git y metio TODOS los files de la Mac dentro aparentemente.

Usando Visual Studio Code en la parte de cambios, me trae los 5000 files que estan dentro de .git, y me alerta de un fatal error, a lo cual quiero revertir el hecho de haber realizado la primera acción.

Alguna idea?

Comment: Si solo fue el `git add` puedes usar `git reset`.

Comment: Lo hice, incluso use git reset --hard. Pero en el VScode me sigue trayendo los mismos files. Este es el estado actual de git https://imgur.com/bAi3TGP .

Comment: Si tu repositorio esta dentro de una carpeta de proyecto (ej. ~/proyecto) no se pueden añadir archivos/carpetas que esten fuera de ella, por lo que imagino que ejecutaste ese comando directamente en la raíz. Otra cosa que git no hace es crear un directorio `.git` si no se ha ejecutado antes `git init`. Lo que puedes hacer es eliminar `.git` de tu directorio raíz `sudo rm -rf .git` y trabajar desde el directorio de tu proyecto, si aun no has añadido tu repo a uno remoto como GitHub puedes hacer eso e iniciar el proceso de nuevo.

Comment: Entiendo lo que me explicas. Mi consulta es la siguiente en base a tu respuesta. Si yo elimino .git, los files que estan dentro se eliminarian también, y mi miedo es si elimino eso, deje de funcionar la pc. Estos archivos que existen dentro de .git, serían como una copia de los archivos originales que se encuentran en sus respectivas carpetas?

Comment: No pasa nada, lo único que sucede es que eliminas tu repositorio local. Si quieres saber como guarda git los cambios puedes checar [esta página](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Packfiles) y si aún desconfias haz lo siguiente: ejecuta este comando en tu terminal `defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES` es para mostrar los archivos ocultos en el finder, reinicia el finder (alt + click derecho en el icono del finder y reiniciar) y mueve el folder de .git a la papelera. Verás que no pasó nada y puedes iniciar un repositorio local nuevo.

Comment: Para ocultar los archivos que estaban ocultos ejecuta el mismo comando solo cambia `YES` por `NO` y de nuevo reinicia el finder.

Comment: Disculpame la demora. Siguiendo tu explicación pude solucionar el problema que tuve. Muchisimas gracias por la ayuda! Saludos!